# New to SQL - SQL Statement Query

Tags: sql

Hi could anyone tell me where I'm going wrong with this SQL Statement:

```
SELECT VAN.MODEL, VAF.MODELDESCRIPTION, Count(VAN.CHASSIS) AS 'Count of CHASSIS'
FROM VAF.csv VAF, VAN.csv VAN
WHERE VAN.MODEL = VAF.MODELID
GROUP BY VAN.MODEL, VAF.MODELDESCRIPTION
```

Instead of just returning the 'Count' or records in VAN (say 4) it is returning what appears to be 4 x the match records in VAF (say 20 records) ie 100?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: Could you provide your data sample?

Comment: I'd try running a query to see the basic results without the join. For example, try an ID that exists. Select all the matching rows for a specific ID first from one table, and then select all the matching rows for that ID from the other table. I imagine you will see that the data does not look the way you thought it did. And if so, you might solve it with the judicious use of DISTINCT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you have to use a derived table, a SELECT statement after the FROM clause

```
SELECT VAN.MODEL, VAF.MODELDESCRIPTION, VAN.[Count of CHASSIS]
FROM (SELECT MODEL, COUNT(CHASSIS) AS [Count of CHASSIS]
      FROM VAN.csv
      GROUP BY MODEL
      ) VAN INNER JOIN VAF.csv VAF ON VAN.MODEL = VAF.MODELID
GROUP BY VAN.MODEL, VAF.MODELDESCRIPTION, VAN.[Count of CHASSIS]
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander (and everyone else), this has done the trick. The reason there is probably some old-styles going on (marc_s above) is that I am having to use MS Query which is importing CSV files data into Excel and I Guess this technology hasn't been updated by Microsoft for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Try `joins`

```
SELECT 
    VAN.MODEL, VAF.MODELDESCRIPTION, Count(VAN.CHASSIS) AS 'Count of CHASSIS'
FROM 
    VAF.csv VAF 
INNER JOIN
    VAN.csv VAN ON VAN.MODEL = VAF.MODELID
GROUP BY 
    VAN.MODEL, VAF.MODELDESCRIPTION
```

Comment: Changing to a proper join doesn't explain the results (although I would encourage making that change)